# Crystal Report to show the data in all pages

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a database field to be shown in page header section. It has a single data, example a100.
The data can be shown in the first page, but not showing in the second page and following. I have tried a few ways but still unable to display the value except in the first page.[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZOC.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy8Lr.png) [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69vab.png)

How to solve this problem i have tried this

Comment: How does the table DataTable1_1 link to the rest of your data? It looks as though it isn't linked so on the first page it works then no other, as no further records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the data in the PAGE header and not in the REPORT header? Has any suppression been done on the Page header section?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).